# What exactly does this Python code do with my function?

Tags: python

`nearest_neighbor` is a function that i call it. This function returns a list... 
I can't understand the meaning of `[0] [1]`.What exactly does this do?

```
nearest = nearest_neighbor(username,users) [0] [1]
```

Thank you...

Comment: Do you understand what ``some_list[0]`` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nearest_neighbor()` function probably returns a list of lists. With `[0][1]` you access the second element from the first list in this list of lists.

Example:

```
# This example function returns a list of lists
def nearest_neighbor():
  return [[i,i+1] for i in range(3)]
```

Output of the example function:

```
>>> nearest_neighbor()
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

When you call the example function like in your code, it returns the second element of the first list, which is a 1in this example:

```
>>> nearest_neighbor()[0][1]
1
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `[0]` and `[1]` you can choose an element from the list. The `[0]` means that you want to access the first element from the list and `[1]` that you want to access the second one.

```
nearest_neighbor[0] # first element from the output of an function
nearest_neighbor[1] # the second element from the output of an function
```

Comment: I know the basics of the Python language!

Comment: @Hamed if you gave me thank you, why didn't you accept my answer>?

Comment: giving thank was because of sharing your time for answering to me and helping